# How to get top class from base class

Tags: c++

This is my example code. I would like to get top class from base or middle class.
How can i do that ? I don't want to specify the top class name anywhere, i know i can write "GetTop< TopClass >();", but i hope, there is a way without that.

Of course, my code shows an error:

"error C2783: 'T *BaseClass::GetTop(void)' : could not deduce template argument for 'T'"

```
class BaseClass
{
public:
BaseClass(){}
virtual ~BaseClass() {}

template < class T >
T* GetTop()
{
    return static_cast<T*>(this);
};

BaseClass * GetBase()
{
    return this;
}
};

class MiddleClass : public BaseClass
{
public:
MiddleClass(){}
virtual ~MiddleClass() {}
};


class TopClass : public MiddleClass
{
public:
TopClass(){}
virtual ~TopClass() {}
};


int __stdcall WinMain( _In_ HINSTANCE hInstance, _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, _In_ LPSTR lpCmdLine, _In_ int nShowCmd )
{
TopClass * t = new TopClass();
MiddleClass * m = static_cast<MiddleClass*>(t);
BaseClass * b = static_cast<BaseClass*>(t);


TopClass * top = m->GetTop();
TopClass * top2 = b->GetTop();

return 0;
}
```

Thank you very much for your ideas :)

Comment: You can't, really. What would happen when you add `class AnotherTopClass: public MiddleClass`?

Comment: Template argument cannot be deduced from a return value.

Comment: I don't fully understand your problem. Is static_cast<TopClass*>() too long for you to type? In that case, why don't you just write an alias function like e.g. `Topclass* ctt(BaseClass* bc){ return static_cast<TopClass*>(bc);}` ?

Comment: MikeMB: Actually yes :) it's long as my class structure is more complicated than this small example. Also, there are 30 different top classes sharing same middleclass and base class. My current design has simple function CastTo< myclass >()  but i thought there is a better way.

Comment: In that case I can only think of writing typedefs that are an abbreviation of your class names or my solution below (return by reference). However, I don't think there is a solution with zero run-time and code length overhead in c++.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you want to do a dynamic_cast<>

You may want C++ to behave like some language with reflection such as C#. That is not true.
This is another post that is similar.

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3049404/apples-oranges-and-pointers-to-the-most-derived-c-class
```

You may be asking something of C++ that it does not have.

```
class basex
{
    public:
    virtual ~basex() {};
};
class middlex : public basex
{
    public:
    //middlex() = default;
};
int dynamic_test()
{
    basex * cbq = new middlex;
    basex * cbq2 = new basex;
    middlex * mcp = dynamic_cast<middlex *>(cbq);
    //should suceed
    if (nullptr != mcp)
    {
        cout << "dynamic cast worked" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "dynamic cast failed" << endl;
    }
    //should fail
    middlex * mcp2 = dynamic_cast<middlex *>(cbq2);
    if (nullptr != mcp2)
    {
        cout << "dynamic cast worked" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "dynamic cast failed" << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

You seem like you really want to do simple casts and the member function does not seem useful

.....................

```
template < class T >
T* GetTop()
```

needs improvement
It is simply doing a cast .... and casts require the destination type
static_cast requires explicit type argument
thus..
GetTop requires explicit type argument

GetTop
is a member function  ... the T can be any class ... the code provided .. has no given parameters for type deduction ... the pointer your provide is ... C++ this ...thus you may call it only TopClass or derived objects. (Lets exclude complicated casts)

```
TopClass * top = m->GetTop();
```

Compiler will try to make sense of right side .............not considering left side
The compiler does not consider the left side for type deduction.. there is no assistance to type deduction .. it will simply try to make sense of the right side
I say that because it seems you might believe the compiler will use the type TopClass for type deduction ... it will not

This will work compile

```
TopClass * top = m->GetTop<TopClass>();
```

But its doing nothing more than an explicit static_cast

Maybe you should state what you are intending to do

Comment: i know, this is working "GetTop<TopClass>();". Let's say, i have lots of derived classes and there is only one top class. Let's say, i want to pass my object to Scene function and it accepts only SceneObject. Class that does not derive SceneObject cannot be passed. MiddleClass is very easy to get because i store references to base class, but i have too many top classes and it just looks horrible to Read class Type and then cast to my right top class. So i thought there is a more clever way how to do that and have code clean and short.

Comment: and dynamic cast is unfortunately slow. I know what i am casting, i don't need to check it.

Comment: @wh1sp3r    Does Scene take a SceneObject or SceneObject & or SceneObject *??? Full Object, Reference, Pointer?  You might want to include that code sample here.  Do you have a container or array of ... SceneObject * .. or TopClass *? If are storing pointers to objects and space permits ... perhaps you can store SceneObjects seperately.   Sometime integers are the same size as pointers.  Perhaps you can store [Object * x, int desired] where desired is true false.  Have you tested dynamic_cast a few times to make sure it is toooooo Sloooooow? Do you have immediate memory contraints.

Answer (score 1):

You could of course write a member function where you return the casted pointer via a reference parameter:

```
template<typename T>
void getTop(T*& result) { result=static_cast<T*>(this); }
```

Your example application then would look like this:

```
TopClass * t = new TopClass();
MiddleClass * m = static_cast<MiddleClass*>(t);
BaseClass * b = static_cast<BaseClass*>(t);


TopClass * top(nullptr);  m->getTop(top);
TopClass * top2(nullptr); b->getTop(top2);
```

Whether you end up with more or less time to write your code and whether this is more or less readable than your current version of course depends on your specific code.

EDIT: A sligly extended version would be:

```
template<typename T>
T*& getTop(T*& result) { 
    result=static_cast<T*>(this); 
    return result;
}
```

and

```
TopClass * top=m->getTop(top);
TopClass * top2=b->getTop(top2);
```

I dont't know how that solution compares to the previous one in terms of performance